# Find a string pattern in a python lists

Tags: python, string, list

I am all new to python and would ask for any help.

I have a text file on which I have to do some cleaning, namely I have to remove some string patterns from the rows. Below what I have done so far:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r")

mylist = []
for i in f:
    mylist.append(i.strip().split('\t')) #removing newlines '\n'

for i in range(0, len(mylist)): # iterate the list to find the string pattern
    #if "@@" in mylist[i]: # I have tried this as well
    if mylist[i].count('@@') > 0:    
        print(mylist[i])
    else:
        print('NOT')
```

This code does not find the string pattern I want.

Comment: Try `for i in f.readlines():` instead of `for i in f`

Comment: You only show code that does not work without any explanation what that code is supposed to do. How exactly would the pattern look? In particular, will the `@@` always be isolated by spaces, or could it be part of a longer "word"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re    
data = [line 
        for line in f.readlines() 
        if re.findall(r'@@', line)] # iterate the list to
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following function: [find()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) . It returns the position where the substring is found.

```
if ("@@".find(mylist[i]) != -1):
    print(mylist[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

i would of made it much simpler:

```
for line in f.readlines(): 
    if '@@' in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print('NOT')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to remove the pattern directly. Why to add more complexity by searching first then remove?

```
mylist = []
for i in f:
    # you can use readline() function here
    mylist.append(i.strip().split('\t')) #removing newlines '\n'

my_new_list = [mystr.replace("@@",'') for mystr in mylist]
```

You can also do it in one line as follows:

```
with open('your_file_path_here','r') as f:
    print([mystr.replace("@@",'') for mystr in f.readlines()])
```

Comment: the stripping to remove `\n` seems redundant, why not use `readlines()` ???

Comment: my main concern was in `replace()` function where the OP needs help in. However, your optimization  is much more continent.